# ProtocolException thrown when uploading image using Retrofit2

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I have a problem with uploading image using retrofit2.

sometimes when my internet connection is weak (like Im downloading something) my mobile application can't upload picture to server and the app throw this exception:

```
 java.net.ProtocolException: expected x bytes but received y
```

the code I use to upload picture is very simple :

```
val body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), image)
 ApiService.create().uploadImage(body)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe({ result ->
                        Log.d("NoError", result.toString())
                    }, { error ->
                        Log.d("FatalError", error.toString())
                    },
                            {}
                    )
```

My question is : 
How to fix this problem?
Should I implement a retry logic?
is there another way to upload files/images in Retrofit2?